# Formula Syntax Error

Tags: formula-field, admin

I keep on receiving the error *Error: Syntax error. Extra ','* on the following formula field, can you please advise me?

```
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Last_Email_Received__c)), 
    IF(
        (ISBLANK(Last_Email_Sent__c)), 
        IF(
            Last_Email_Received__c + 2 < NOW(), 
            'Time Exceeded', 
            ''
        )
    ),
    IF(
        Last_Email_Received__c + 2 < NOW(), 
        'Time Exceeded', 
        ''
    )
),
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Last_Email_Received__c)), 
    IF(
        NOT(ISBLANK(Last_Email_Sent__c)), 
        IF(
            Last_Email_Received__c + 2 < Last_Email_Sent__c, 
            'Time Exceeded', 
            'Yes'
        ),
        IF(
            Last_Email_Received__c + 2 < Last_Email_Sent__c, 
            'Time Exceeded', 
            'Yes'
        )
    )
))
```

Comment: What is the use case that you are trying to achieve with this formula?

Comment: I need to show if the last email was responded within 48 hours or not. We already have these two fields that are linked to WF rules that get updated when a new email is received or sent. I just need to display a text in relation to them.

Comment: Formatting your formula according to best practice (group things into independent "statements", break them out onto their own lines, indent an extra level each time you encounter a `(` ) as I have done for you this time should always be your first step when trying to debug a formula. Our brains just don't handle a bunch of parenthesis well, so it's ridiculously easy to misplace an open or close paren.

Comment: Also, when you're running into an error message and looking for help with it, you should _always_ copy/paste the error message here (verbatim, trying to shorten or paraphrase error messages almost always means you're removing important information).

Comment: Derek, the error message has been added to the question. Thank you for advising.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see a parenthesis that shouldn't have been

Here is the corrected code:

```
IF(
    NOT(ISBLANK(Last_Email_Received__c)) && NOT(ISBLANK(Last_Email_Sent__c)), 
        IF(
            Last_Email_Received__c + 2 < Last_Email_Sent__c, 
            'Time Exceeded', 
            'Yes'
        ),
        IF(ISBLANK(Last_Email_Sent__c),
            'No email Sent', 
            IF(ISBLANK(Last_Email_Received__c),
            'No email Received',
            ''
            )
        )
)
```

Comment: Thank you! I have this error now *Error: Incorrect number of parameters for function 'IF()'. Expected 3, received 2*

Comment: I received the same error unfortunately

Comment: I write again the code grouping if